# comparison of more than one multivariate nls models in r

Tags: r, nls

dear members,
              I am trying to identify which of the two multivariate nls models is more of a good fit. I came to know that you can use anova and f tests for univariate nls models to know which one is better.

Can that be applied to multivariate nls models also? If yes, how do you compare them?

Can AIC/BIC be used to compare them? If yes, what is the condition and how to get AIC/BIC for multivariate nls models in R?

Comment: By multivariate do you mean multiple independent variables?

Comment: Yes; multiple independent predictors

Comment: An ANOVA can be used to compare the models, if they are nested then additionally an F-test is executed. Otherwise you can always compare models with log likelihood scores or AIC/BIC.